# Java programming- error tracking

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I have a raffle draw program that used to have many commands and components, etc.
But I would like to make it a lot simpler by omitting many commands or components such as buttons or labels.
When I tried to do so, errors arose (42 errors) all of which say:

```
error: class, interface or enum expected.
```

Can somebody help me track down these errors?

BTW, here's my code (UPDATED):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Case extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    static Case app=new Case();
    JDesktopPane desk=new JDesktopPane();

    Connection cn=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Statement stat=null;

    JInternalFrame log=new JInternalFrame("WELCOME!", true,true,true,true);
    JInternalFrame game=new JInternalFrame("Hi! Welcome to RAFFLE DRAW by BSIT22C");

    int arr[]=new int[10];
    int range=0;

    JTextField gametext=new JTextField("",2);
    JTextField txtuser=new JTextField("",20);

    JMenuBar gamebar=new JMenuBar();
    JMenu mnuf=new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem fnew=new JMenuItem("New Game");
    JMenuItem fquit=new JMenuItem("Quit Game");
    JMenuItem flogout=new JMenuItem("Logout");

    JPanel pnllog=new JPanel();
    JPanel pnlgame=new JPanel();

    JButton blog=new JButton("Login");
    JButton bcan=new JButton("Cancel");

    JButton bgen=new JButton("Generate Number Set");
    JButton bsubmit=new JButton("Submit Number");

    JCheckBox[] ck=new JCheckBox[10];

    JLabel lblives=new JLabel("");
    JLabel lbcons=new JLabel("");

    int life=5;
    int userscore=0;
    int cons=0;


    public void init()
    {

        setContentPane(desk);
        desk.add(log);
        desk.add(game);

        game.setVisible(false);
        game.setSize(800,600);
        game.setContentPane(pnlgame);
        setJMenuBar(gamebar);
        gamebar.add(mnuf);
        mnuf.add(fnew);
        mnuf.add(fscore);
        mnuf.add(flogout);
        mnuf.add(fquit);

        for(int ctr=0;ctr<10;ctr++)
        {
            ck[ctr]=new JCheckBox();
        }
        for(int ctr2=0; ctr2<10; ctr2++)
        {
            pnlgame.add(ck[ctr2]);
        }

        ck[0].setEnabled(false);
        ck[1].setEnabled(false);
        ck[2].setEnabled(false);
        ck[3].setEnabled(false);
        ck[4].setEnabled(false);
        ck[5].setEnabled(false);
        ck[6].setEnabled(false);
        ck[7].setEnabled(false);
        ck[8].setEnabled(false);
        ck[9].setEnabled(false);

        game.setSize(750,100);
        pnlgame.add(gametext);
        pnlgame.add(bsubmit);
        pnlgame.add(bgen);
        pnlgame.add(bup);
        pnlgame.add(lbtimer);
        pnlgame.add(lbtest);
        pnlgame.add(lbscore);
        pnlgame.add(lbachieve);
        pnlgame.add(lblives);
        pnlgame.add(lbcons);
        lbachieve.setText("Bonus");


        bgen.addActionListener(this);
        bsubmit.addActionListener(this);

        setJMenuBar(gamebar);
        gamebar.add(mnuf);
        mnuf.add(fnew);
        mnuf.add(fscore);
        mnuf.add(flogout);
        mnuf.add(fquit);

        log.setVisible(true);
        log.setSize(300,100);
        log.setContentPane(pnllog);

        pnllog.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        pnllog.add(blog);
        pnllog.add(bcan);


        setJMenuBar(gamebar);
        gamebar.add(mnuf);
        mnuf.add(fnew);
        mnuf.add(fscore);
        mnuf.add(flogout);
        mnuf.add(fquit);

        fnew.setEnabled(false);
        blog.addActionListener(this);
        bcan.addActionListener(this);
        fnew.addActionListener(this);
        fquit.addActionListener(this);
        flogout.addActionListener(this);
        app.setSize(1024,800);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ex)
    {
        Object[] options={"Easy", "Normal", "Hard"};

        if(ex.getSource()==fnew)
        {
            bsubmit.setEnabled(false);
            gametext.setEditable(false);
            int option2=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Choose difficulty", "New Game",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);
            if(option2==0)
            {
                for(int ctrck=0; ctrck<10; ctrck++)
                {
                    ck[ctrck].setSelected(false);
                }
                lbtest.setText("");
                gametext.setText("");
                lbachieve.setText("");
                lblives.setText("");
                lbcons.setText("");
                lbscore.setText("");
                life=5;
                userscore=0;
                bgen.setEnabled(true);
                cons=0;
                log.setVisible(false);
                game.setVisible(true);
                range=10;
            }
            else if(option2==1)
            {
                for(int ctre=0; ctre<10; ctre++)
                {
                    ck[ctre].setSelected(false);
                }
                lbtest.setText("");
                gametext.setText("");
                lbscore.setText("");
                lbachieve.setText("");
                lblives.setText("");
                lbcons.setText("");
                life=5;
                userscore=0;
                bgen.setEnabled(true);
                cons=0;
                log.setVisible(false);
                game.setVisible(true);
                range=20;
            }
            else if(option2==2)
            {
                for(int ctrn=0; ctrn<10; ctrn++)
                {
                    ck[ctrn].setSelected(false);
                }
                lbtest.setText("");
                gametext.setText("");
                lbachieve.setText("");
                lblives.setText("");
                lbcons.setText("");
                lbscore.setText("");
                life=5;
                userscore=0;
                bgen.setEnabled(true);
                cons=0;
                log.setVisible(false);
                game.setVisible(true);
                range=40;
            }

    }
    else if(ex.getSource()==fscore)
    {
        {
            int hsconf=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you want to view the current score rankings?","Please Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(hsconf==0)
            {
                log.setVisible(false);
                game.setVisible(false);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }   
        log.setVisible(false);
        game.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(ex.getSource()==flogout)
    {
        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you really want to quit playing?", "Do you want to exit?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(option==0)
        {
            for(int q=0; q<10; q++)
            {
                ck[q].setSelected(false);
            }
            lbtest.setText("");
            lbachieve.setText("");
            lblives.setText("");
            lbcons.setText("");
            lbscore.setText("");
            life=5;
            userscore=0;
            cons=0;
            bgen.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            log.setVisible(true);
        }
        for(int e=0; e<10; e++)
        {
            ck[e].setSelected(false);
        }
        lbtest.setText("");
        lbachieve.setText("");
        lblives.setText("");
        lbcons.setText("");
        life=5;
        userscore=0;
        cons=0;
        bgen.setEnabled(true);
        log.setVisible(true);
        game.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(ex.getSource()==fquit)
    {
        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you really want to quit playing?", "Do you want to exit?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(option==0)
        {
            for(int r=0; r<10; r++)
            {
                ck[r].setSelected(false);
            }
            lbtest.setText("");
            lbachieve.setText("");
            lblives.setText("");
            lbcons.setText("");
            life=5;
            userscore=0;
            cons=0;
            bgen.setEnabled(true);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            log.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    else if(ex.getSource()==bcan)
    {
        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you really want to quit playing?", "Do you want to exit?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(option==0)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            log.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    else if(ex.getSource()==bgen)
    {
        bsubmit.setEnabled(true);
        gametext.setEditable(true);
        app.generate();
    }

    else if(ex.getSource()==bsubmit)
    {

    try
        {
            app.cmpans();
            if(ck[0].isSelected()&&ck[1].isSelected()&&ck[2].isSelected()&&ck[3].isSelected()&&ck[4].isSelected()&&ck[5].isSelected()&&ck[6].isSelected()&&ck[7].isSelected()&&ck[8].isSelected()&&ck[9].isSelected()==true)
            {
                int win = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you want to go for another round?","Congratulations! You WIN!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if(win==0)
                {
                    for(int r=0; r<10; r++)
                    {
                        ck[r].setSelected(false);
                    }
                    lbtest.setText("");
                    life=5;
                    userscore=0;
                    gametext.setText("");
                    lbscore.setText("");
                    lblives.setText("");
                    lbcons.setText("");
                    cons=0;
                    bgen.setEnabled(true);

                    log.setVisible(false);
                    game.setVisible(true);
                }
                else if(win==1)
                {
                    log.setVisible(false);
                    game.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
            else if(life<=0)
            {
                int gameover=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Sorry, you lost!","GAME OVER!",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                if(gameover==0)
                {
                    game.setVisible(false);
                    log.setVisible(false);
                }
                else if(gameover==1)
                {
                    gametext.setText("");
                    lbscore.setText("");
                    lblives.setText("");
                    lbcons.setText("");
                    lbtest.setText("");
                    lbscore.setText("");
                    bgen.setEnabled(false);
                    bsubmit.setEnabled(false);
                    game.setVisible(false);
                    log.setVisible(false);
                }

            }       
        }catch(Exception ebak){}

    }   

    else if(ex.getSource()==blog)
    {   
        fnew.setEnabled(false);
        bsubmit.setEnabled(false);
        gametext.setEditable(false);
        Object[] options1={"Easy", "Normal", "Hard"};
        log.setVisible(false);
        fnew.setEnabled(true);
        int option3=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Choose difficulty", "New Game",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options1, options1[1]);
        if(option3==0)
        {
            for(int ctrck2=0; ctrck2<10; ctrck2++)
            {
                ck[ctrck2].setSelected(false);
            }
            lbtest.setText("");
            gametext.setText("");
            lbachieve.setText("");
            lblives.setText("");
            lbcons.setText("");
            lbscore.setText("");
            life=5;
            userscore=0;
            bgen.setEnabled(true);
            cons=0;
            log.setVisible(false);
            game.setVisible(true);
            range=10;
        }
        else if(option3==1)
        {
            for(int ctre=0; ctre<10; ctre++)
            {
                ck[ctre].setSelected(false);
            }
            lbtest.setText("");
            gametext.setText("");
            lbscore.setText("");
            lbachieve.setText("");
            lblives.setText("");
            lbcons.setText("");
            life=5;
            userscore=0;
            bgen.setEnabled(true);
            cons=0;
            log.setVisible(false);
            game.setVisible(true);
            range=20;
        }
        else if(option3==2)
        {
            for(int ctrn=0; ctrn<10; ctrn++)
            {
                ck[ctrn].setSelected(false);
            }
            lbtest.setText("");
            gametext.setText("");
            lbachieve.setText("");
            lblives.setText("");
            lbcons.setText("");
            lbscore.setText("");
            life=5;
            userscore=0;
            bgen.setEnabled(true);
            cons=0;
            log.setVisible(false);
            game.setVisible(true);
            range=40;
        }

    }
}


    public void generate()
    {
        for(int z=0; z<=1; z++)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                Random rdm=new Random();
                arr[i] = rdm.nextInt(range)+5;
            }
            lbtest.setText("Random Numbers: "+arr[0]+"-"+arr[1]+"-"+arr[2]+"-"+arr[3]+"-"+arr[4]+"-"+arr[5]+"-"+arr[6]+"-"+arr[7]+"-"+arr[8]+"-"+arr[9]);
            bgen.setEnabled(false);
            gametext.setText("");
        }

    }

    public void cmpans()
    {
        boolean success=false;
        boolean boo=false;
        String txget;
        txget=gametext.getText();
        String pars;
        int ans;
        pars=gametext.getText();
        ans=Integer.parseInt(pars);

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {

            if(ans==arr[i])
            {
                userscore=userscore+10;
                lbscore.setText("Score: "+userscore);
                ck[i].setSelected(true);
                arr[i]=0000;
                gametext.setText("");
                lblives.setText("life: "+life);
                lbcons.setText("cons: "+cons);
                success=true;
            }
            else
            {
                boo=true;
            }
        }

        gametext.setText("");
        if(success==true)
        {
            cons++;
            if(cons==2)
            {
                lbachieve.setText("You're a GOOD GUESSER!");
                userscore=userscore+20;
            }
            else if(cons==4)
            {
                lbachieve.setText("You're an AMAZING GUESSER!!");
                userscore=userscore+50;
            }
        }
        else if(boo==true)
        {
            cons=0;
            life--;
            lblives.setText("life: "+life);
            lbcons.setText("cons: "+cons);
        }

    }

}
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        app.init();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out which of these lines make the errors arise.

Comment: The error messages *tell you* which lines are causing the error. Perhaps you should tell us this information?

Comment: Check that all your curly brackets match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you've got too many closing braces at the end of your *enormous* (300+ lines!) `actionPerformed` method. That means you're closing your class declaration, leading to the subsequent errors.

To avoid this problem in the future:

- Get your IDE to indent your code. Your indentation goes wonky on line 156 to start with (just below the declaration of `option2`) and also on line 382 (just below the declaration of `options1`). It's distinctly odd in other places too.
- Keep your methods *much, much* shorter. When a method start taking more than about a page to display, you should really be looking to refactor it into smaller methods. (Ideally, earlier than that - I like methods which are fewer than ~20 lines, personally, although I don't have a hard and fast limit.) Methods of the size of your `actionPerformed` one are a maintenance *nightmare*.

Comment: @JonSkeet_what? no. this was MY program. i made it myself. so if you guys see a bunch of errors here, it's because im still JUST A STUDENT.

BTW, im down to the last two errors....

Comment: @cryzone: Where did I suggest it was anything other than your program? I'm saying I found the errors by copying and pasting the code you'd given, and then looking at where the compiler showed the errors.

Comment: @JonSkeet_im sorry, i thought you accused me of getting all my codes from the net and copy/pasting them to my IDE. funny, almost all the forums i've gotten into thought that i copy/paste codes from the net. i know my program looks funny. i even get lost in it myself. but i really do research works... i even sleep at way past 2am in the morning and get up at 5am to go to school. well, i hope you don't get me wrong. my point is that im still just a student... :)